# How to loop through model and get each id in a varaible

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hello I am new to laravel, I want to loop through a data table and get each id of it in a variable.
So i did it like this, but unfortunatly nothing works

```
$station_id = 0;
$stations = Station::all();

foreach ($stations as $station) {
    $station_id =  $station->id;
}
return $station_id;
```

this only showing the last id;

Comment: You know that this will only output the last id as you return station_id after the loop that sets it to something different each time? What would be the purpose of this? I suspect there is a better way to do this but I need to know your use case.

Comment: Are you trying to get all IDs in a collection or array? So for example you'd want the result to be an array of IDs that looks something like this `[1, 5, 7]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is loop all of the result set and add the `ids` to an array. First, you need an empty array:

```php
$stations = Station::all();
$station_ids = [];

foreach ($stations as $station) {
    $station_ids[] =  $station->id;
}
return $station_ids;
```

Once you have all `station_ids`, you can then loop in your view like this

`Controller`

```php
$stations = Station::all();
    $station_ids = [];

    foreach ($stations as $station) {
        $station_ids['ids'] =  $station->id;
    }
    return view('view.blade.php',$station_ids);
```

`view`

```php
@foreach($ids as $id)
      {{ $id->fieldname}}
  @endforeach
```

You can not assign a single variable in a loop to a single id.

Answer (score 2):

The way you are trying it your `$station_id` will be set to the very last ID.. If you want to have an array of ids from the stations just use this:

```
$stations = Station::pluck('id')->toArray();
```